# When there are multiple liquidity pools for the same pair on SundaeSwap, which one is used for my trade?

Tags: defi, sundaeswap, liquidity-pools, dex

Let's say we have two liquidity pools for token X and ADA (X/ADA)

- pool 1 has 10 X and 10 ADA locked -> price is 1
- pool 2 has 20 X and 10 ADA locked -> price is 2

What happens if I buy X/ADA now? In this situation, SundaeSwap shows the price of one of the pools, but it's not always the one with the better price (depending on if you buy or sell).

Could I order a buy and a sell and it would automatically buy for 1 ADA and sell for 2 ADA?

**Example:**

There are 2 pools for MIN/ADA:
[image]

I want to sell MIN for 0.3 ADA on the first pool. That seems to work:

[image: sell MIN/ADA]

But when I buy, I obviously would want the price of the second pool and buy 1 MIN for 0.27 ADA. But also here it shows the price of the first pool, which is more expensive.

[image: buy MIN/ADA]

Is this only a display issue and I would actually be able to buy 1 MIN for 0.27 ADA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the CIO of SundaeSwap on Discord it's "picking the pool that gives you the best rate for your trade size". So in theory I believe, yes, it should only be a UI issue.

However, I have not confirmed this myself and the answer is from early December, so it might also be outdated.

https://discord.com/channels/830939534174453800/915669612350292038/917624514043600996

[image]